# Why does a function have integral but no antiderivative?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

My complex variable teacher mentioned that a function could have no antiderivative but could be integrable, any explanation?

Comment: I think your teacher meant no antiderivative in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: Their specific language and context would be nice. Riemann integrability? Lebesgue integrability? Antiderivative at all? Antiderivative in terms of elementary functions?

Comment: You may have misheard her because the adjective "elementary" is needed. The vast majority of functions we encounter have no "nice" antiderivatives.

Comment: Just what it says on the tin: some functions do not possess an antiderivative; that is, there exists no formula (usually in terms of elementary functions) such that differentiating it gives you the original function. However, many of these are still amenable to numerical integration (via Riemann sums or whatever else)

Comment: Take a look at [Thomae's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function), which is Riemann integrable over $[0,1]$ but has NO antiderivative.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If we're talking about complex numbers, we usually refer to integrals along a path. Let $\gamma$ be the counterclockwise path around the unit circle. Then
$$ \int_\gamma \frac{1}{z} dz = 2 \pi i,$$
but there is no antiderivative of $\frac{1}{z}$ that is defined on all of $\mathbb{C} \setminus \lbrace0 \rbrace$ (see [complex logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm)).

Answer (score 2):

As I said in the comment, I don't think it has anything to do with "no antiderivative in terms of elementary functions". It is perfectly possible for a function to be Riemann integrable but not be the derivative of ANY function. Take a look at [Thomae's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function):
$$f(x)=\begin{cases} 0\text{ if $x$ is irrational} \\\frac 1 q \text{ if }x= \frac p q \in\Bbb Q, (p,q) \text{ coprime}\end{cases}$$
which is so pathological that it can never have an antiderivate of any kind, but amazingly, it is still Riemann integrable.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by "has an antiderivative". It's provable that the function $f(x) = e^{-x^2}$ has no antiderivative **that can be written down in terms of combinations of** $e^x, \sin(x), x^n, \log(x),\dots$ **using sums, products, quotients, and compositions.** On the other hand $\int_a^b e^{-x^2} dx$ exists for all $a,b\in {\mathbb R}$. Because of that you can write down an antiderivative: $F(x) = \int_0^x e^{-t^2} dt$. This function (not of the previously described form) satisfies $F'(x) = f(x)$.

Comment: And if you're lucky and this function is rather important in  a branch of maths, it may even be named after you.